# Get Outlook email body without signature, if signature was added (VBA)

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried isolating the body of a received Outlook email in a macro, using the following code:

```
Dim inspector As Outlook.inspector, email As Outlook.MailItem, body As String
Set inspector = Application.ActiveInspector
Set email = email.subject
body = email.Body
```

The problem is, when I print out the contents of this variable in a MsgBox, it has the person's signature included. Is there a different attribute other than `Body` to use for this? Some way to isolate the body of the mail item without the sender's signature, if they added one?

For bonus points: if `email` is an email that was forwarded to me, `Body` also includes information (header details/metadata, the body itself, and a signature if present) from all the **previous emails** in the forwarding chain. Is there a way to isolate just the body of the current mail item rather than all the associated ones?

Comment: NO. there's no separate attribute for signature. For the editor and object model everything inside is just `Body`. Only way is to parse the content and run some code over it to exclude signature(s).

Answer (score 0):

Outlook places the new signature inside the "`_MailAutoSig"` bookmark, which can be accessed through `Document.Bookmarks.Item("_MailAutoSig")`, where `Document` can be retrieved from `Inspector.WordEditor`.

Comment: "has the person's signature included" appears to indicate received mail not created mail.

Comment: For clarification, niton is correct. I'm only talking about received mail. Editing my question to make this more obvious.

Comment: Correct. The bookmark is only used on the messages being composed. Once the message is sent (or received) the bookmark is gone.